# Changing font size causes gpar error with R histogram plot

Tags: r, histogram, r-markdown

My histogram causes an error when I try to change the subtitle fontsize.

```
hist(data, breaks=18, col = "azure3", main = "$$$$", sub = "$$$$", sub_gp=gpar(fontsize=3), main_gp=gpar(fontsize=13))
```

I get the following error: "Error in gpar(fontsize=3)": Could not find function "gpar" Calls: Anonymous...hist.default -> plot -> plot.histogram ->plot.window"

I find it strange because I am using the exact same code for the fontsizing of a mosaic plot, in another R markdown file and there it works fine.

Comment: `hist` is a base graphics function. `gpar` is a grid graphics function and only works with grid graphics. Try `hist(data, breaks=18, col = "azure3", main = "$$$$", sub = "$$$$", 
     cex.axis=2, cex.lab=2, cex.main=2, cex.sub=2)`. The `cex.***` arguments set font sizes relative to the default size.

Comment: In my case, the Could not find function `gpar` error was because I had not load the `grid` library by adding `library(grid)` in the beginning of the code.